# Using android opencv apps without downloading opencv sdk manager

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have followed a tutorial which allowed me to install opencv statically - It works since i added this code to the activity

```
 static
    {
        if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.d("RANCHU", "Failed");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("RANCHU", "SUCCESS Opencv");
        }
    }
```

It always shows success,yet whenever I use the app with no opencv sdk manager I get the following message:

**OpenCV manager pacakge was not found! try to install it?**

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I had to search the web for a long time until I found the solution I decided to solve it once and for all for everyone :

First I followed This video which is very helpful (All credit goes to the rightful owner)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTw_GIQNbD8

Later In my activity I have added

```
static
    {
        if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.d("DD", "Failed");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("DD", "SUCCESS Opencv");
        }
    }
```

After that in on resume you should add :

```
mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
```

and that is it , if you have the line // `OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this,mLoaderCallback);`

Remove it! Before I removed it , it didnt work.

Hope it helps someone